# XML problems, text not showing up android

Tags: android, xml

I created a table in my xml for displaying some information. But the text is not loading into ito the table. I know the text has a value because it shows up in my log.

My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"

    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

                <!-- Card Contents go here -->


                <ImageView android:id="@+id/breweryImage"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dip"/>


            </LinearLayout >

        </FrameLayout>





        <TableLayout

            android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

                    <!-- Card Contents go here -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableStatTitles"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            android:padding="5dip" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/year"
                                android:text="Year Est."
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textStyle = "bold"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"

                                ></TextView>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/bAvg"
                                android:text="Avg"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textStyle = "bold"
                                android:textSize="10sp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"

                                ></TextView>






                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableStat"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            android:padding="5dip" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/yearEnter"
                                android:text=""
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                ></TextView>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/avgEnter"
                                android:text=""
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                ></TextView>




                        </TableRow>

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout >

            </FrameLayout>





        </TableLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

                <!-- Card Contents go here -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/beerDescriptionTitle2"
                    android:textStyle = "bold"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Description:"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    ></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/breweryDescription"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:padding="5dip"

                    ></TextView>





            </LinearLayout >

        </FrameLayout>




    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My async task which is loading the data in looks like this:

```
public class GetBreweryDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public GetBreweryDataJSON(Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting brewery information");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{

            Log.d("brewery", "in try");
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result);

            Log.d("brewery", result);


            //String name = getName(o);
            //String description = getDescription(o);
            //String year = getYear(o);
            //String icon = getIcon(o);

            String name = o.getString("name");
            String description = o.getString("description");
            String year = o.getString("year");
            String icon = o.getString("picture");
            String avg = o .getString("avg");




            //set image
            ImageView im1 = (ImageView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.breweryImage);
            ImageDownloadTask imageD = new ImageDownloadTask(im1);
            imageD.execute(icon);

            //create text views
            TextView breweryYear = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.yearEnter);
            TextView breweryAvg = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.avgEnter);
            TextView breweryDescription = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.breweryDescription);

            String yearPrint = "";

            year = yearPrint + year;

            //set text
            breweryYear.setText(year);

            Log.d("brewery" , year);
            Log.d("brewery" , avg);

            breweryDescription.setText(description);
            breweryAvg.setText(avg);


        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String getName(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }



    public String getIcon(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("images").getString("large");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }

    public String getDescription(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("description");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }


    public String getYear(JSONObject json){
        String holder;



        try{
            holder = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("established");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of what I am getting:

[image]

Comment: can you try and add a layout_height to the text, or just input dummy text to verify that it would be visible?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I forgot to open and close with table tags in my XML. I have the rows, but never initiate the table.